# I can't hide my menu using overflow-x: hidden over the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Even though I apply overflow-x: hidden to my body, the horizontal scrolling still works and I can't give it a solution.

I've been looking for solutions through the internet, but I can't solve the problem. That is why I turn here so that you can help me. Thank you very much!

Attached html, scss and javascript:

HTML:

```
<!-- HEADER -->

<div id="home" class="container-fluid home__hero">
    <nav class="menu">
        <div>
            <h4 class="logoMenu">Guinda Social Media</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="linkMenu liHome"><a href="#home" class="linkHome">Home</a></li>
            <li class="linkMenu liAbout"><a href="#about" class="linkAbout">About</a></li>
            <li class="linkMenu liTrabajos"><a href="#trabajos" class="linkTrabajos">Trabajos</a></li>
            <li class="linkMenu liContacto"><a href="#contacto" class="linkContacto">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="contenedorBurger">
            <div class="burgerBtn">
                <div class="linea1"></div>
                <div class="linea2"></div>
                <div class="linea3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- FIN HEADER -->

    <!-- HERO -->

    <div class="row justify-content-center align-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 home__hero__col1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="3000">
            <h1><span class="home__hero__h1--social">social</span><span
                    class="home__hero__h1--guinda flicker-2">guinda</span><span
                    class="home__hero__h1--media">media</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 home__hero__col2">
                <section class="example example--2 bounce-top">
                    <span class="scroll-icon">
                        <span class="scroll-icon__dot"></span>
                    </span>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

@import "variables.scss";

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.logoMenu {
    font-family: $fuente;
    color: $rojo;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ul li a {
    font-family: $fuente;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: $rojo;
    font-style: italic;
}

ul li a:hover {
    font-family: $fuente;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: $rojo;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.burgerBtn {
    display: none;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */

/* IPAD */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
    
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        top: 15vh;
        right: 0;
        background-color: $rojo;
        z-index: 1;
        transform: translate(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    .liHome {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .liAbout {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    }

    .liTrabajos {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    }

    .liContacto {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.6s;
    }

    .active {
        transform: translate(0%);
    }

    
    ul li a {
        font-family: $fuente;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        color: white;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    
    ul li a:hover {
        font-family: $fuente;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
    }
    
    .logoMenu {
        font-family: $fuente;
        color: $rojo;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    /* ICONO BURGER */
    
    .contenedorBurger {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .linea1 {
        background-color: $rojo;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    }
    
    .linea2 {
        background-color: $rojo;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    }
    
    .linea3 {
        background-color: $rojo;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    .toggle .linea1  {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
    }
    
    .toggle .linea2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .toggle .linea3 {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
    }
    
    .burgerBtn {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

/* CELULAR */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        top: 15vh;
        right: 0;
        background-color: $rojo;
        z-index: 1;
        transform: translate(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .liHome {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .liAbout {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    }

    .liTrabajos {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.4s;
    }

    .liContacto {
        margin-right: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        transform: translate(500px);
        transition: transform 1s ease-in-out 0.6s;
    }

    .active {
        transform: translate(0%);
    }
    
    ul li a {
        font-family: $fuente;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        color: white;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    
    ul li a:hover {
        font-family: $fuente;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
    }
    
    .logoMenu {
        font-family: $fuente;
        color: $rojo;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    /* ICONO BURGER */
    
    .contenedorBurger {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    
    .linea1 {
        background-color: $rojo;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    }
    
    .linea2 {
        background-color: $rojo;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    }
    
    .linea3 {
        background-color: $rojo;
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    .toggle .linea1  {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
    }
    
    .toggle .linea2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .toggle .linea3 {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
    }
    
    .burgerBtn {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
var burger = document.querySelector('.burgerBtn')
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links')
var linkHome = document.querySelector('.linkHome')
var linkAbout = document.querySelector('.linkAbout')
var linkTrabajos = document.querySelector('.linkTrabajos')
var linkContacto = document.querySelector('.linkContacto')
var liActiveHome = document.querySelector('.liHome')
var liActiveAbout = document.querySelector('.liAbout')
var liActiveTrabajos = document.querySelector('.liTrabajos')
var liActiveContacto = document.querySelector('.liContacto')

burger.addEventListener('click', openMenu)

function openMenu() {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active')
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle')
    liActiveHome.classList.add('active')
    liActiveAbout.classList.add('active')
    liActiveTrabajos.classList.add('active')
    liActiveContacto.classList.add('active')
}

linkHome.addEventListener('click', function closeMenu() {
    nav.classList.remove('nav-active')
    burger.classList.remove('toggle')
})

linkAbout.addEventListener('click', function closeMenu() {
    nav.classList.remove('nav-active')
    burger.classList.remove('toggle')
})

linkTrabajos.addEventListener('click', function closeMenu() {
    nav.classList.remove('nav-active')
    burger.classList.remove('toggle')
})

linkContacto.addEventListener('click', function closeMenu() {
    nav.classList.remove('nav-active')
    burger.classList.remove('toggle')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by replacing overflow-x into display style value.

JavaScript example:

document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.display = "none"

Html can display even objects with overflow-x or visibility hidden values.

In html just add display:none inside style=""(<p style ="display:none;")

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example in cause of body element: http://tpcg.io/SCsHMMzO
If i don't understand right, just replace overflow-x: hidden to display: none for your main element, that contains all elements that you try to hide. Theres no way to make scrolling bar desapear by using overflow-x style value.